# Why isn't my component showing the ContentChild via a directive?

Tags: angular, typescript

It seems that you should use a directive to target a content child from a directive ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673978/how-do-i-select-a-contentchild-of-a-native-element-in-angular-6)).

But why isn't my component recognising the component marked with the directive?

**./my.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  Directive,
  ContentChild,
  AfterContentInit
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[trigger]"
})
export class TriggerDirective {}

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component",
  template: ` <ng-content></ng-content> `
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild(TriggerDirective) trigger: TriggerDirective;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("===> ", this.trigger);
    // output: '===> undefined'
  }
}
```

**./my.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MyComponent, TriggerDirective } from "./my.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent, TriggerDirective], // declared it here
  exports: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

**./app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h1>Title inside app component.</h1>
    <app-my-component>
      <button #trigger>Click me</button>
    </app-my-component>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**./app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MyModule } from "../my-component/my.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, MyModule], // imported the module here
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: `#trigger` actually creates a reference variable to the element, iam not sure if that works to be honest. You can just write `trigger` to make the selector work instead

Comment: Ah oké. There also seems to be something else thats wrong. Removed it in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-boyd-cgrxr

Comment: Thank you for the reproducer, you'll need to export the `TriggerDirective` from `MyModule` in order to use it on an element inside of `AppComponent`

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I've written up the full example. How can I give you the credit for this answer?

Comment: I merely gave hints from a first glance, a full fledged answer should include explanation and a working example - just like the one you just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the full answer based on the help of @Mike S.

**./app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "app-root",
template: `
  <h1>Title inside app component.</h1>
  <app-my-component (submit)="doSomething($event)">
    <!-- 1. use the directive without '#' since that would make it a reference variable -->
      <button trigger>Click me</but
    <button trigger>Click me</button>
  </app-my-component>
`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**./trigger.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[trigger]"
})
export class TriggerDirective {}
```

**./my.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ContentChild, AfterContentInit } from "@angular/core";

import { TriggerDirective } from "./trigger.directive";

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component",
  template: ` <ng-content></ng-content> `
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  // 2. declare it as a content child
  @ContentChild(TriggerDirective) trigger: TriggerDirective;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("===> ", this.trigger);
  }
}
```

**./my.module.ts**

3. Declare the trigger, and export it for usage in the module where the component lives where you'd like to use it.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MyComponent } from "./my.component";
import { TriggerDirective } from "./trigger.directive";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent, TriggerDirective],  // <- declare
  exports: [MyComponent, TriggerDirective] // <- and export
});
export class MyModule {}
```

**./app.module.ts**

4. And finally make sure the entire module is included in the module where you're using it.

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MyModule } from "../my-component/my.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, MyModule], // <-
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```